# Injecting services into Razor page's ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, blazor, maui

I have a page:

```
@page "/registration";

@inherits RegistrationPageViewModel;

<h3>
    @Localizer["Registration"]
</h3>
```

And its ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class RegistrationPageViewModel : ComponentBase
    {
        public IStringLocalizer<AppLocalizations> Localizer;
        public IValidator<RegistrationPageViewModel> _validator;
        public RegistrationPageViewModel(IValidator<RegistrationPageViewModel> validator)
        {
            _validator = validator;
        }
      ...
```

Now, when I try to inject into the view model stuff like validators, I get errors like this:

> CS7036    There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
> parameter 'validator' of
> `RegistrationPageViewModel.RegistrationPageViewModel(IValidator<RegistrationPageViewModel>)`

How can I fix this? I guess it has something to do with dependency injection and the fact that my view model is a child of ComponentBase, but I have no clue where to go from there.

Here's how my DI looks like:

```
public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .RegisterAppServices()
                .RegisterViewModels()
                .RegisterViews()
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

            return builder.Build();
        }

        public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterValidators(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
        {
  mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IValidator<RegistrationPageViewModel>, RegistrationValidator>();

            return mauiAppBuilder;
        }
        
        public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterViewModels(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
        {
            mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<MainPageViewModel>();
            mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<LoginPageViewModel>();
            mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<RegistrationPageViewModel>();
            return mauiAppBuilder;
        }
        
        public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterViews(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
        {
            mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<LoginPage>();
            mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<RegistrationPage>();

            return mauiAppBuilder;
        }
          ...
```

Validator

```
public class RegistrationValidator : AbstractValidator<RegistrationPageViewModel>
    {
        public RegistrationValidator(IStringLocalizer<AppLocalizations> stringLocalizer)
        {
```

Comment: The service container is looking for a service with this pattern `IValidator<RegistrationPageViewModel>` but your registered service that I think you are intending to inject has the pattern `<IValidator, RegistrationValidator>`.  You need to resolve which is the correct way to register the specific validator.  Without knowing what the objects and interfaces look like I would be guessing to suggest the correct configuration.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I tried like that as well, didn't help

Comment: [Polite] So show us the class pattern and Ctor for your `IValidator` and `RegistrationValidator`. Or tell us whose library you are using.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis added, it's FluentValidator, I was able to use it with [Inject] attribute without going through constructor, but of course I am still curious as to reason why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your `RegistrationPageViewModel` is a Component

```
public class RegistrationPageViewModel : ComponentBase
```

Which you then inherit in your page:

```cs
@page "/registration";

@inherits RegistrationPageViewModel;
```

And you also register the base class as a service:

```cs
mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<RegistrationPageViewModel>();
```

While you might have patched this together to make it work, I'm pretty sure registering components as services is not good practice.  I can see all sorts of problems.

`RegistrationPageViewModel` should be a normal class that you inject into your page.

Looking at your configuration you appear to be registering Components.

```cs
    mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<LoginPage>();
    mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<RegistrationPage>();
```

Why?

Components are managed by the Renderer, not the services container.

Comment: I see, what would be a better approach then? I just need to use my DI services in those ComponentBase derived ModelViews

Comment: Take a look at this answer I recently posted to a specimen question.  It shows which services to register and how to register and consume them.  Any queries, ask.  The repo is here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.EditForm